# webpack4 with ejs when icluding partial fails with Unexpected identifier

Tags: templates, include, ejs, webpack-4

I use ejs under webpack4 for templating and I define an entry point like

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './src/views/index.ejs',
                debug: true,
                files: {
                    css: ['main.css'],
                    js : ['bundle.js']
                },
            })
```

now in `index.ejs` I try to include a partial like as follows

```
<% include partials/footer %>
```

but fails with the following error

```
ERROR in ./src/views/index.ejs (./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/views/index.ejs)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I was trying to google similar reported problems but none are working in my case